# how to control list of timepickers in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a list of time pickers in my application to let the user chose the opening times for his store, so he can chose from_time,to_time and the day as shown in the picture.
the problem is i want to control this list so i can add a new time, delete, modify
I am using Antd V3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but here is what I have got

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-curran-kkx10

by the way, that snippet could help you to understand the use case of keys with list in React.